# Piping Python output to NetCat - time.sleep() breaks output?

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows-subsystem-for-linux, netcat

I am attempting to dump a python script's output to netcat using WSL on windows. In one terminal, I have my python program & netcat set up in listener mode. In another terminal, I am connecting to this listener and expecting to see my python output. The below code works and I am able to do this successfully, but when adding time.sleep(1) inbetween function calls I do not receive any Python output. Why is this?

I have tried using the print() function instead of sys.stdout.write(). I've tried different nc configurations.

Python producer script:

```
import time
from sys import stdout

def generate_stream_data():
    stdout.write('some text\n')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    iterations = 10000
    while iterations > 0:
        generate_stream_data()
        time.sleep(1)  # this causes nothing to get piped to nc
```

Piping the python output in WSL:

```
python above_code.py | nc -lk localhost 9999
```

In another WSL terminal:

```
nc -v localhost 9999
```

Commenting out `time.sleep(1)` lets me see my output in my second terminal. I have tested the standalone Python program, and it successfully prints 'some_ text' to console with the 1sec delay. Why does adding this cause me to not see anything in netcat?

Comment: Might have something to do with how WSL interacts with the pipe. The python docs state: `any caught signal will terminate the sleep() following execution of that signal’s catching routine. Also, the suspension time may be longer than requested by an arbitrary amount because of the scheduling of other activity in the system.`